# Laravel 8 не видит маршрут

Tags: php, laravel

Делаю авторизацию на сайте и при логаюте не видит роут

```
Route::get('/logout', [\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'logout']) ->name('logout-user');

Route [logout-user] not defined. (View: C:\Users\racer\PhpstormProjects\internet-shop\internet-shop\resources\views\mainTemplates.blade.php)
```

в чем может быть проблема?

в mainTemplates

```
<li><a href="{{ route('logout-user') }}">Выйти</a></li>
```

Comment: Возможно пробел вот здесь ") ->name"?

Comment: Нет, не из-за этого

Comment: попробуйте имя изменить, без дефиса, например. либо проверить корректность написания, что буквы точно не русские где-то попались

Comment: Я уже пробовал изменять и переписывать в ручную и копировать, не помогает(( не могу понять почему

Comment: А не находится ли `Route::get` в какой-либо группе? Попробуйте выполнить в консоле `php artisan route:list`, может даст подсказку